# Why is printf working but scanf isn't?

Tags: c

Alright so I have to create a weather program and when I try running the code, I get no errors but it will just print the "enter a starting temperature" and the "enter an ending temperature". However it won't let me input the data for it. Is there anything I need to change? I know I haven't completed the code but I just wanted to test out the inputs before continuing with the rest of the code. Thanks for the help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    float celcius, fahrenheit, kelvin, ending, interval;
    int c, f, k, temp;

    printf("which temperature is being input? (C,F,K) ");
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    if (temp == c)
    {
        printf("enter a starting temperature");
        scanf("%f", &celcius);
        printf("enter an ending temperature");
        scanf("%f", &ending);
        fahrenheit = celcius * 9 / 5 + 32;
        kelvin = celcius + 273.15;
    }
    if (temp == f)
    {
        printf("enter a starting temperature");
        scanf("%f", &fahrenheit);
        celcius = fahrenheit - 32 * 5 / 9;
        kelvin = fahrenheit - 32 * 5 / 9 + 273.15;
        printf("enter an ending temperature");
        scanf("%f", &ending);
        if (temp == k)
        {
        }
        printf("enter a starting temperature");
        scanf("%f", &kelvin);
        fahrenheit = kelvin - 273 * 1.8 + 32;
        celcius = kelvin - 273.15;
        printf("enter an ending temperature");
        scanf("%f", &ending);
    }
}
```

Comment: I normally a leading space in *scanf() format strings at least after the first one IIRC, due to the '\n' after the user enters data.

Comment: check out `fgets` function, you could use it instead of `scanf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
if (temp == c)
```

is comparing the newly-read value in `temp` to the undefined value in the uninitialized variable `c`. This is undefined behavior.

You probably meant

```
if (temp == 'c')
```

to compare against a character, but then you also need:

```
char temp;
if (scanf("%c", &temp) == 1)
{
  if (temp == 'c')
  {
    /* more code here */
  }
}
```

Note that checking the return value of `scanf()` helps make the program more robust, and avoids further uses of uninitialized values (if `scanf()` fails to read something, you shouldn't read the destination variable since it won't have been written to).

Comment: The 'c' for sure helped and your code helped me a lot! however, why did you add "== 1"? what is the significance of that? To indicate if it is true?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (temp == c)
```

You are comparing temp with an uninitialized value of c

same for

```
if (temp == f)
```

then every thing will be working fine , to make it more user friendly , put a '\n' in printf's

like this,

```
printf("enter a starting temperature \n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
printf("which temperature is being input? (C,F,K) ");
scanf("%d", &temp);
```

you ask for a character to be input, but then you try to scan for an `int`. This will throw off all the rest of your `scanf()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable temp is declared as an integer. Indeed, scanf() wants to read an integer (%d), but gets a char.
Therefore, you read temp as a char. 
Furthermore you may use

```
9.0/5.0
```

instead of

```
9/5
```

Furthermore, using the switch statement would increase the readability.